# How to split a string of concatenated values into specific columns

Tags: sql, json, oracle, parsing

Our database stores hours for multiple days as a single string (format is `JSON`, see below).  I need to extract the hours for any given day. The problem is the `JSON` does not hold the days in a guaranteed order.

I tried `substr` and `instr` this way:

```
SUBSTR(hours_xltd,
       INSTR(hours_xltd,'"MONDAY"', 1, 1)+1,
       INSTR(hours_xltd,',',1,2) - INSTR(hours_xltd,',',1,1)-1) as Monday
```

which gives me `MONDAY":"0800-1800","F` but what I need is:

```
Monday
0800-1800
```

I need the same thing for `Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday`. This is the desired output (each day on its own column which is denoted by the pipe in my example);

```
   monday |   tuesday | wednesday |  thursday |    friday |  saturday |    sunday
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0800-1800 | 0800-1800 | 0800-1800 | 0800-1800 | 0800-1800 | 0800-1800 | 0800-1800
```

Sample data:

```
{
 "default": {
    "standard_hours": {
       "TUESDAY":"0800-1800",
       "SATURDAY":"0800-1400",
       "WEDNESDAY":"0800-1800",
       "THURSDAY":"0800-1800",
       "SUNDAY":"",
       "MONDAY":"0800-1800",
       "FRIDAY":"0800-1800"}
 }
}        

{ 
 "default": {
    "standard_hours": {
       "MONDAY":"0800-1800",
       "TUESDAY":"0800-1800",
       "WEDNESDAY":"0800-1800",
       "THURSDAY":"0800-1800",
       "FRIDAY":"0800-1800",
       "SATURDAY":"0800-1800",
       "SUNDAY":"0800-1800"}
  }
}
```

Please help me with reviewing the code? I can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: Will you always have 2 rows and 7 columns of output?  Will the data always have a value for each day of the week?  Do you always want the monday value to be in the first column?  Oh, and what version of Oracle are you using?  Oracle has built-in support for JSON in 12.1.  If not, are you using a third-party JSON package?

Comment: To answer some of your questions, No, I will have multiple rows since the data ranges from 1 to many. However, I will always have 7 columns of output. Not all days will have a value (example "SATURDAY":"","SUNDAY":""). I'm currently using 12.1.

Answer (score 0):

Let's skip the rant about what a bad idea it is to store structured data in an unstructured format like JSON and move on to the solution.

We can extract the day names and hours using regular expressions.  As we know, [using regex in production code is a bad thing](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247), so when we need to it's a good idea to keep it as clear as possible.

The first common table expressions extracts the DAY:HOUR strings and unpivots them into a result set (there are several variations on this string splitting  trick).  The second CTE separates the DAY and the HOUR strings.  The main query uses aggregation to pivot the rows.

```
with std as ( select id
                     , regexp_substr(substr(json_str,31), '[^,]+', 1, level) as day_str
              from t23
              connect by level <= 7 )
     , hrs as ( select distinct id
                       , regexp_substr(day_str, '([A-Z]+)') as d_str
                       , regexp_substr(day_str, '([0-9\-]+)') as h_str
                 from std )
select id
       , max(case when d_str = 'MONDAY' then h_str end) as monday
       , max(case when d_str = 'TUESDAY' then h_str end) as tuesday
       , max(case when d_str = 'WEDNESDAY' then h_str end) as wednesday
       , max(case when d_str = 'THURSDAY' then h_str end) as thursday
       , max(case when d_str = 'FRIDAY' then h_str end) as friday
       , max(case when d_str = 'SATURDAY' then h_str end) as saturday
       , max(case when d_str = 'SUNDAY' then h_str end) as sunday
from hrs
group by id
order by id
/
```

Note that I needed an ID column to make the pivotimg work.

```
 18  ...
 19  order by id
 20  /

        ID MONDAY    TUESDAY   WEDNESDAY THURSDAY  FRIDAY    SATURDAY  SUNDAY
---------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- --------- ---------
         1 0800-1800 0800-1800 0800-1800 0800-1800 0800-1800 0800-1400
         2 0800-1800 0800-1800 0800-1800 0800-1800 0800-1800 0800-1800 0800-1800

SQL>
```

Comment: I started playing with this but because of a lack of visualization, I cannot get it to work. I played with the extraction of DAY:HOUR below:

`select 
ypid, 
hours_xltd,
regexp_substr(hours_xltd, '([A-Z]+)') as d_str,
regexp_substr(hours_xltd, '([0-9\-]+)') as h_str
from listing_extract
where ypid in ('481973535','483796785','495850252','1452');`

using my table name and primary key, can you help me understand your script?